# I cant make the asterisk operator overloading it does nothing on the code below it should repeat my string 5 times but it doesnot

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I can't make the asterisk operator overloading work. It does nothing on the code below. It should repeat my string 5 times, but it doesn't.

**.h file**

```
class Mystring
{
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Mystring &rhs);
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, Mystring &rhs);

private:
    char *str;      // pointer to a char[] that holds a C-style string
}
```

**.cpp file**

```
Mystring Mystring::operator * (int n) const {

    size_t buff_size = std::strlen(str) *n + 1;
    char *buff = new char[buff_size];
    std::strcpy(buff,"");
    for (int i =1; i <=n; i++)
        std::strcat(buff,str);
    Mystring temp{buff}; 
    delete [] buff;
    return temp;
};


int main(){

    Mystring s3{"abcdef"};  
    s3*5;
    cout << s3 << endl; 
}
```

Comment: This statement s3*5; has no effect.

Comment: Please just use `std::string` and avoid the longer code and potential mistakes that come with trying to do character buffers yourself. Also, consider the `new` and `delete` keywords advanced topics; they're essentially never needed in user code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yep you are right. I was not sure if to write this comment, because example in the question is obviously incomplete, but because `Mystring` was constructed using aggregate initialization I thought it actually might also be an issue. If it is, even though OP already accepted the answer that seems to solve the problem, he might still experience UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `operator*` will repeat the string, but you throw away the result of `s3*5`.

Try `cout << s3*5 << endl;`.